# JQuery click() on part of SVG object inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to implement a function that hides some layers of a SVG.
It works somewhat, but the reaction to user clicks is inconsistent. Some times the show-hide functions get called, and some times nothing happens. If I double click the text in the svg gets selected... How can implement a better click event handler?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title> Switch - demo</title>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>



                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js"></script>




                <script type='text/javascript' src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.svg.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.svganim.js"></script>

                <style type='text/css'>
                #svgbasics { width: 600px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #484; }


                </style>



                <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[


                function drawOpenSwitch(svg){

                    //Boolean states for switches:
                    var f1closed = false;
                    var q1closed = false;

                    var changeSwitch = function (){
                        $('#closed3Pswitch').hide();
                        $('#closed3Prelay').hide();



                        $('#f1Button').click(function() {

                            if(f1closed == false){
                                $('#open3Pswitch').hide();
                                $('#closed3Pswitch').show();
                            }else{
                                $('#closed3Pswitch').hide();
                                $('#open3Pswitch').show();
                            }
                            f1closed=!f1closed;
                        });


                        $('#q1Button').click(function() {
                            if(q1closed == false){
                                $('#open3Prelay').hide();
                                $('#closed3Prelay').show();
                                }else{
                                $('#closed3Prelay').hide();
                                $('#open3Prelay').show();
                            }
                            q1closed=!q1closed;
                        });
                };



                svg.clear();
                var switchElement=svg.load('./fullschema_connected_combined.svg', {onLoad: changeSwitch, addTo: true, changeSize: true});



                }



                $(window).load(function(){
                $(function() {
                    $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawOpenSwitch});
                });





                });//]]>

                </script>


                </head>
                <body>
                <div id="svgbasics"></div>


                </body>


                </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in that I was using lines with arrow-ends (Inkscape)... the lines where part of the q1Button, but the arrow heads were not. Therefore it only worked when I had the mouse pointer just above the thin lines underneath the arrow head. Replacing the figure group called q1Button & f1Button solved the problem.